# Activate venv and run python script from shell script

Tags: python, shell, bots

I am testing a (python) bot script before using it with crontab. I was advised to run a shell script that runs the python script in the crontab. In order for the shell script to run, I need to activate the venv. This is where the problem is. When I try to run run_socialbot.py, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gsb/socialbot.py", line 3, in <module>
    from instapy import InstaPy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'instapy'
```

Even though instapy is installed in the venv. And when I open up the interpreter with "python3" and try to import instapy while the venv is activated, it works fine. Here is the shell script code:

```
#! /bin/bash

source /home/gsb/venv/bin/activate 

/usr/bin/python3 /home/gsb/socialbot.py
```

Can anyone help out? thanks in advance

I'm running this at a digitalocean server. Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 2):

Your shell script activates the venv but then it explicitly calls an absolute path `/usr/bin/python3`. That's not the venv Python executable. The whole point of activating the venv is to set `$PATH` so that `python` points at the venv interpreter.

In your wrapper script, change it to:

```
python /home/gsb/socialbot.py
```

Alternatively you can remove the bash wrapper script entirely, and put a venv shebang into `socialbot.py`, then use this Python file in the crontab directly. Make the file executable, and add as the first line:

```
#!/home/gsb/venv/bin/python
```